# how to parse password during the find command in linux?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, ubuntu

I need to parse password during find a file in remote linux system, how can I read a remote directory in linux?

I tried one:

```
ssh root@192.168.5.6 "find /var/www/home" sshpass -p pass
```

it didn't work properly in linux, if any one face this solution, please let me know...

I tried two:

```
 opendir(IN, "root@192.168.5.6:/var/www/home") || die "can't open !";
```

I tring also perl but it didn't work properly,

How can I start? How can I read a remote directory?

Comment: Why not use an [ssh key](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) and avoid password use at all?

Comment: yes it working but I read different remote directory as random, so i can't change ssh key at the time, so i parse password during find,.. and another way I can't use opendir function in linux is it possible or not?

Comment: "I read different remote directory as random" - what do you mean? An ssh key will work for all directories on a remote machine. Are you using multiple remotes?

Comment: k we can use same password to different server? k how can i start this and can please you explain... how do it..

Answer (score 1):

use [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign).

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, user => $user, password => $password, autodie => 1);
my $ls = $sftp->ls($dir);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($ls);
```

Comment: it get errors can't locate IO/Pty.pm, I search ppm but it not found module,  how to install IO::Pty module ...

Comment: Which OS and version/distribution are you using?

Comment: There is no such thing as Ubuntu 11.3. Anyway, both Net::SFTP::Foreign and IO::Pty are available from Ubuntu repositories: `sudo apt-get install libnet-sftp-foreign-perl libio-pty-perl`

Comment: sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700, errors

Comment: `sudo` is mis-configured on your system. Is there any other way you know to become root on that machine? Do you known the root password? You can also try using other package installer as the `Ubuntu Software Center`.

Answer (score 0):

It wont work that way in perl. Try something like this:

```
open(IN, "$cmd|")
```

where `$cmd` is the command that works for you from the command line.

Comment: it work for command, but my question i want to read a directory in linux  system, how to do this?